# How to fade between ImageViews in an Android app?

Tags: java, android

I know how to do this for 2 images but what about 3 images.

```java
public void fadeBardock(View view) {
    ImageView bardock = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bardock);
    ImageView goku = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goku);
    ImageView gohan = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gohan);

    bardock.animate().alpha(0 f).setDuration(3000);
    goku.animate().alpha(0 f).setDuration(4000);
    gohan.animate().alpha(1 f).setDuration(5000);
}
```

After clicking on button I'm directly getting the third image without getting the second image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
bardock.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(3000);
goku.setAlpha(0f);
goku.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(3000).setStartDelay(1500);
goku.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(3000).setStartDelay(4500);
gohan.setAlpha(0f);
gohan.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(3000).setStartDelay(6000);
```

You can change duration and start delays to achieve your optimal result.

Answer (score 0):

On More than one imageviews,
1. Create an array of ImageView.
2. Initialize the views in it.
3. assign unique id's to each view in same loop.

[ Another thing is, you can initialize the views in one for loop in onCreate() and then on button click, apply another for loop for animation.]

4. Now, using an index of array, assign an animation to each view with delay from previous views.
5. Start animation after the loop and check.
   Hope it helps.